# Arduino Cryposuite and C programming syntax

Tags: c

Hi i am new to C programming. I am trying to implement a SHA1HMAC on my data before sending the data out to my app.

This is the code to generate the hash

```
Serial.println("Result:");
Sha1.initHmac(hmacKey,20);
Sha1.print("Test");
printHash(Sha1.resultHmac());
Serial.println();
```

This is the method to print out the hash. I do not understand what is being done here. I would like to store the hash in a variable so I could compare the string output of the hash with another hash in string

```
void printHash(uint8_t* hash) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]>>4]);
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]&0xf]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It simply converts the number to its hex representation by taking the quotient (`>>4`) and remainder (`&0xF`) and using them as indices in an array of hex characters (`"0123456789abcdef"`). And it does it for the 20 numbers in the `hash` array.

Comment: Sha1 hash result is then stored in hash[0], hash[1] .. hash[19].

Is there a way to store the result inside a variable?

Comment: 20 bytes because HMAC-SHA-1 signature is 20 bytes long - the size of `int` has nothing to do with that, as the parameter is a byte array (with 20 bytes): not an `int`.

Comment: Oh duh it's an array. Late :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the hash in a variable, because it's saved already in a variable inside of your Sha1 object. The function `Sha1.resultHmac()` will return an pointer to an array of 20 elements:

```
Sha1.initHmac(hmacKey, 20);
Sha1.print("Test");
uint8_t* hash = Sha1.resultHmac(); // the variable hash[] has 20 fields, from hash[0]...hash[19]
```

To compare the hash later with a second hash, you can write an simple function like this:

```
int compareHash(uint8_t* hash1, uint8_t* hash2) {
  int retVal = 1;
  for (size_t i=0; i<20; i++) {
    if(hash1[i] != hash2[i]){
      retVal = 0;
      break;
    } 
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

Which will return 0 if the hashes are different or 1 if they are identical.

Comment: I'll be hashing it in my node.js server which will send out the second hash data in a string. So I'm actually thinking if its possible to compare the two string hash

Comment: @Exceptions Please include all information about your specific problem in your question itself - there is no mention of string comparing, so people won't be able to help you properly if this information is missing.